# Minimum number of items to cover all cases

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to find the minimum number of items needed to cover all the cases in a key-value pair setting.

```
pd.DataFrame({'key': ['AAA',  'BBB', 'BBB','BBB',  'CCC', 'CCC'],
  'value': ['1',  '1', '2','4', '1','3']})
```

I have 4 values (1,2,3,4) and in order to cover them all I need at least the following keys

- BBB is the only one to give me 2 and 4
- CCC is the only one to give me 3
- and both BBB and CCC give me 1

So in that case the minimum number of keys to include all the values is **2** (BBB and CCC)

Is there a model/library to help with this type of calculation?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is [explicitly off-topic](/help/on-topic). You could fix that by showing your attempt at doing this with a [mre], and asking a question about a problem you had with said attempt. People will usually include a library that can already do this in their answers if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach the problem with `.mode()` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['AAA',  'BBB', 'BBB','BBB',  'CCC', 'CCC'],
  'value': ['1',  '1', '2','4', '1','3']})

lst = list()
while not df.empty:
    x = df['key'].mode().iloc[0]
    df = df[~df['value'].isin(df.loc[df['key'].eq(x), 'value'])]
    lst.append(x)

print(lst)
# ['BBB', 'CCC']
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are describing is closely related to the set cover problem. Finding a hitting set is NP-hard.

I have implemented your solution as follows:

```
keys = pd.unique(df['key'])
values = pd.unique(df['value'])
x = len(keys)
count = x
result = keys

for i in range(1 << x):
  subset_keys = [keys[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))]
  subset_values = []  
  for key in subset_keys:
    subset_values += list(df.query("key=='"+key+"'")['value'])
  if len(set(subset_values))==len(list(values)) and len(subset_keys)<count:
    result = subset_keys

print(result)
```

Complexity is O(2^n) where n is the number of unique keys.